# Get the data for the full penultimate calendar month + data for the same month, but in 2 previous years

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working in PostgreSQL environment and I have the following problem: let's say today is April 8th, 2019 and I want to pull the full list of user IDs who opened their account in the penultimate month (so from Feb 1st till Feb 28th, 2019) + list of user IDs who opened their account in the same month, but in years 2017 and 2018 (so in Feb'18 and Feb'17).

If we assumed that today is June 25th 2019, I would want to pull the list for the following periods:
- 1st till 30th April 2019;
- 1st till 30th April 2018;
- 1st till 30th April 2017.

I have this SQL code at the moment. As you can see, I have to alter the dates in the WHERE clause every month. Can someone advise me on how I could solve this problem?

```
SELECT 
        deposit_id, 
        to_char(activation_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as placement_start_date,

FROM fixed_term_plan

WHERE 
activation_date BETWEEN Date '2019-01-01' AND Date '2019-01-31' or activation_date BETWEEN Date '2018-01-01' AND Date '2018-01-31' or activation_date BETWEEN date '2017-01-01' AND Date '2017-01-31'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  I am thinking:

```
SELECT deposit_id, 
       to_char(activation_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as placement_start_date,
FROM fixed_term_plan ftp
WHERE extract(month from activiation_date) = extract(month from (now() - interval '2 month'));
```